# How do I write the expression based on a combinational analysis?

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c01ms.png]

I don't understand how to write the expression based on a Karnaugh map, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two distinct parts to writing the expression result. Clearly, you have to first figure out the best way to "paint" the k-map. That seems to have already been done. And since your question is *not* about how to do that, but how to get an expression once the correct painting (or boxing) has been done, it's not so hard. (Since ocrdu already got the picture showing up in your question, I'll rely on it rather than repeating it here.)

Let's start with the green-boxed pair. It lies on a single row that requires \$q_3=0\$ and \$q_2=1\$. You *must* exclude all the other rows. So you are stuck starting out here with this partial term: \$\overline{q_3}\:q_2\$. Looking at the columns you can see that it spans two columns. What these two columns share is that \$q_1=0\$ and that it doesn't matter what \$q_0\$ is. So this means you don't need to worry about \$q_0\$ but do need to retain the fact that \$q_1=0\$. So the final term is \$\overline{q_3}\:q_2\:\overline{q_1}\$.

This is just one of them. You'll need to get each one by a similar process. But you can see that the 2nd term in the picture's expression matches the one I just performed for the green-boxed region, right?

Do the same thing for the others. See if you can get there. If not, add a comment about what problems remain for you and I'll try to add what you still need.

It appears you aren't connecting the dots, so to speak. So here's my labeling for your chart:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply jonk, I was confused by the way you wrote q3 = 0 and q2 = 1, I thought q2 was the first bit in the column and q3 came after, in which case q3 would become equal to 1 and q2 would be 0.

Comment: I am stuck here: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/406979441890295839/1043235538288771082/unknown.png

I got the bottom and upper one correct.

Comment: Am I going crazy? Is the q2 not the first bit, "0"? https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/545823859006242828/1043237265243123772/Skarmavbild_2022-11-18_kl._19.51.59.png

Comment: @bittscoterie I usually take it given that the *first* listed \$q_i\$ is the higher order bit. So maybe I just lucked out? Anyway, I see that q3 is the higher order and q2 is lower order for the left side. I see that q1 is higher order and q0 is lower order on the top.

Comment: Thanks @jonk, I solved the problem.